# I forked someone's forked repo. How can I change my repo to go to the original repo?

Tags: github, branch, git-fork

This is what the current situation is...

Repo C is a fork of Repo B

Repo B is a fork of Repo A

Inside Repo C, I worked on a branch that only exists in Repo B.

How can I change github so that Repo C is only a fork of Repo A?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change GitHub so that Repo C is only a fork of Repo A?

It would be easier to:

- create repo D, as a fork of repo A, and clone it locally
- add local-D as a remote in repo C
- push your branch you were working on to local-D
- push that branch from local-D to origin/D, and do on working from there in D.